# Filtering a string filed against a string list in mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Trying to filter a collection using a string field against a string list.

```
public List<Case> getCases(List<String> doctorIds) {

 Query query = new Query();
 query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("primaryDoctorId").in(doctorIds));
 return mongoTemplate.find(query, Case.class);

}
```

The filtering mongo class

```
public class Case {

   private String primaryDoctorId;

    public String getPrimaryDoctorId() {
    return primaryDoctorId;
   }

   public void setPrimaryDoctorId(String primaryDoctorId) {
    this.primaryDoctorId = primaryDoctorId;
  }

}
```

But this is not working as expected, even-though there is a record that fulfill this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can try query filter building using [BasicDBObject](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) and [BasicDBList](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/BasicDBList.html)

```
public List < Case > getCases(List < String > doctorIds) {
    BasicDBList docIds = new BasicDBList();
    docIds.addAll(doctorIds);
    DBObject inClause = new BasicDBObject("$in", docIds);
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("primaryDoctorId", inClause);

    MongoCursor < Document > cursor = collection.find(query).iterator();
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine. I created a collection with couple of documents; "case" collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e539c699753e47a7525da78"), "primaryDoctorId" : "1", "other" : "str-1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e539c729753e47a7525da79"), "primaryDoctorId" : "2", "other" : "str-2" }
```

**Spring Mongo Java Code:**

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
List<String> docIds = Arrays.asList("1", "3", "5");
Query qry = new Query(Criteria.where("primaryDoctorId").in(docIds));
List<Case> list = mongoOps.find(qry, Case.class);
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output returns: `"1"`

**Case.java:**

Note that I added the `toString()` method so that the output prints the `primaryDoctorId`.

```
public class Case {

    private String primaryDoctorId;

    public String getPrimaryDoctorId() {
        return primaryDoctorId;
   }

    public void setPrimaryDoctorId(Stringint primaryDoctorId) {
        this.primaryDoctorId = primaryDoctorId;
  }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "docId: " + primaryDoctorId;
    }
}
```